# How do you concatenate two (or more) dataframes into a panel

Tags: python, pandas

I was recently trying to concatenate two dataframes into a panel and I tried to use `pd.concat` with `axis=2`

Consider the dataframes `df1` and `df2`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 3), list('abc'), list('def'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 3), list('abc'), list('def'))
```

Then I tried

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=2)
```

[image]

This looked the same as if I had used `axis=1`.  Maybe pandas is just checking if `axis` evaluates to `True`.  Let's try

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis='This Has To Break...Right?')
```

[image]

Nope!  Did not break.  Ok, so how do I concat two dataframes along `axis=2`

I could

```
pd.Panel(np.stack([df1, df2])).to_frame()
```

[image]

But this ignores the indices and will not align them if they were different.

I'd want something that looks like

```
panel

<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 3 (major_axis) x 3 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 0 to 1
Major_axis axis: a to c
Minor_axis axis: d to f

panel.to_frame()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are looking for, but:

```
pd.Panel(np.stack([df1, df2]), major_axis=df1.index, minor_axis=df2.columns ).to_frame()

                    0         1
major minor                    
a     d      0.630339  0.020119
      e      0.736730  0.874750
      f      0.530833  0.637081
b     d      0.759991  0.499921
      e      0.651995  0.310123
      f      0.005724  0.759712
c     d      0.510702  0.067634
      e      0.367993  0.893205
      f      0.030383  0.591366


data = {0 : df1,   1 : df2}
pd.Panel(data)

<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 3 (major_axis) x 3 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 0 to 1
Major_axis axis: a to c
Minor_axis axis: d to f


data = {0 : df1,   1 : df2}
pd.Panel(data).to_frame()

                    0         1
major minor                    
a     d      0.630339  0.020119
      e      0.736730  0.874750
      f      0.530833  0.637081
b     d      0.759991  0.499921
      e      0.651995  0.310123
      f      0.005724  0.759712
c     d      0.510702  0.067634
      e      0.367993  0.893205
      f      0.030383  0.591366
```

Comment: Method 1 only works because the indices and columns are already aligned.  Method 2 is what I ended up with in the answer I provided and why I gave you a +1.  What I wanted was something that looked and felt like `pd.concat`.  Anyway, better you to get the answer than me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pd.Panel` constructor and pass a dictionary of dataframes.

```
def concat2(dfs, keys=None):
    if keys is None:
        keys = range(len(dfs))
    return pd.Panel({k:v for k, v in zip(keys, dfs)})
```

This feels like what a `pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, keys=keys)` should do.

---

#### Demonstration

```
concat2([df1, df2]).to_frame()
```

[image]

```
concat2([df1, df2], ['df1', 'df2']).to_frame()
```

[image]